# String from ajax execute as jquery

Tags: jquery, string, chain

I make an ajax call and I receive a string back from the server (this could also be another string and chain):

```
thisitem.parent().parent().hide()
```

Now I want to excecute that jquery chain. I believe `eval()` is the answer, but I understand that that's dangerous?

So what's the alternative? Or is `eval()` not dangerous for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/ or https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js library to convert json to javascript objects. Actually browsers have native support for this but not all of them. So using an another tool is recomended for now.

Answer (score 0):

javascript is a script. maybe u can response a flag as (1,2) not a script string.  i think .

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.getScript()

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: ? i receive a json string back from the server not a script file

Comment: You never said that in the question. Am I a magician? Do I magically know that? Are you sure it's a JSON string, cos JSON is an object, if it is a string, this function will read it as a script. If it is an object, simply read it as a script and change the object variable to be a function returning the string you want.

Comment: ok sorry about that it's indeed an object

"If it is an object, simply read it as a script and change the object variable to be a function returning the string you want."

do you have an example?

Comment: See @Luffy 's answer, the solution is there.